Different language in citation appearing in csquotes's \foreignblockquote
Citations in a language other than that of my document do not appear correctly formatted in \foreignblockquote. Look at the example below: I'd like the citation on the third line to be formatted like the citation on the second line, i.e., with "and" instead of "et". What do I have to do to make it so? In case it matters, I compile with lualatex + biber.
\begin{filecontents}{temp.bib}
@Article{dummy,
    author={F. Firstname and S. Secondname and T. Thirdname},
    date={2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
    \babelprovide{english}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear-comp,
    ]{biblatex}
    \bibliography{temp}

\begin{document}
\textcite{dummy} OK

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
    \textcite{dummy} OK
\end{otherlanguage}
 
\foreignblockquote{english}{\textcite{dummy}} KO
\end{document}

Here is the result:


\foreignblockquote uses otherlanguage* and if you try this environment instead of otherlanguage, you get “et”.

OK, thanks a lot for your swift answer! It works like a charm. I overlooked the subtle difference between otherlanguage and its starred version.

As it's documented in csquotes, \foreignblockquote uses otherlanguage* that doesn't enable biblatex strings and extras.
The following patch seems to work.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{dummy,
    author={F. Firstname and S. Secondname and T. Thirdname},
    date={2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=authoryear-comp,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\csq@otherlang@star}[1]{%
  \csuse{otherlanguage*}{#1}%
  \csuse{abx@extras@#1}%
  \csuse{abx@strings@#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blockquote{\textcite{dummy}}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\blockquote{\textcite{dummy}}
\end{otherlanguage}

\foreignblockquote{english}{\textcite{dummy}}

\end{document}


